# How to handle mixed precision dates using R as.POSIXct

Tags: r

I have a list of a series of dates, with mixed precision. Most have the format "1930-02-06T10:00:00", but a few have the format "2130-02-06" which I want to treat as 2130-02-06T00:00:00.

When I use

`df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date,tz=Sys.timezone())`

I lose times from the data because some of the datetimes are missing time. I can write a little conversion routine

```
fixDateTime <- function (s) {
  if(nchar(s) == 10) {
    return (paste(s, "00:00:00"));
  } else {
    return (str_replace(s,"T", " "));
  }
}
```

and then do

```
df$DATET <- as.POSIXct(fixDateTime(df$date),tz=Sys.timezone())
```

But that doesn't work because fixDateTime is actually given an array and I don't know how to adapt for that. I'm not sure which way to try to solve this. (and I'm sure this shows how newbie I am to R)

Comment: Can you turn them into strings and then normalise them a bit using stringr and then use lubridate to bring them back as datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ronak's answer is good as it uses just base R.  Another solution is offered by the `anytime()` function of the [anytime](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/anytime/index.html) -- it does not need any formats.

```
 R> library(anytime)
 R> anytime(c("1930-02-06T10:00:00", "2130-02-06"))        # localtime by default
 [1] "1930-02-06 10:00:00 CST" "2130-02-06 00:00:00 CST"
 R> anytime(c("1930-02-06T10:00:00", "2130-02-06"), tz="UTC", asUTC=TRUE) #override
 [1] "1930-02-06 10:00:00 UTC" "2130-02-06 00:00:00 UTC"
 R>
```

So you can have it as UTC, or in your local time.

The main key is that *not giving hours:minutes:seconds is generally seen as midnight* when you parse to datetime rather than date.  So you may not need a helper function

Answer (score 4):

You can work with your `fixDateTime` function if you use `ifelse` which can handle vectors instead of `if`/`else` which works for scalars. Keeping everything in base R, we can do

```
fixDateTime <- function (s) {
  ifelse(nchar(s) == 10, paste(s, "00:00:00"), sub("T", " ", s))
}
```

and then use it in `as.POSIXct`

```
as.POSIXct(fixDateTime(x), tz = "UTC")
#[1] "1930-02-06 10:00:00 UTC" "2130-02-06 00:00:00 UTC"
```

**data**

```
x <- c("1930-02-06T10:00:00", "2130-02-06")
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out lubridate is all you need:

```r
library(lubridate)

data <- c("1930-02-06T10:00:00", "2130-02-06")

ymd_hms(data, truncated = 3)
#> [1] "1930-02-06 10:00:00 UTC" "2130-02-06 00:00:00 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>